# Why does this preg_replace not work? Removing HTML entities

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Why does this preg_replace to remove HTML entities not work?

```
// Remove all HTML entities
$text = preg_replace('/&[A-Za-z0-9]+?;/',' ', $text);
```

I'm simply trying to replace all HTML entities like ( &###; , < , and etc. ) with spaces, but I seem to be missing something because it is not replacing them and I'm utterly confused now.

---

**Test case**

*Code:*

```
// Remove all HTML entities
$title="&#9829;&#9829;&#9829; I like cats &#9829;&#9829;&#9829;";
echo "BEFORE : ".$title."\n";
$title2 = preg_replace('/&[A-Za-z0-9]+?;/e',' ', $title);
echo "AFTER : ".$title2."\n";
```

*Output:*

```
BEFORE : ♥♥♥ I like cats ♥♥♥
AFTER : ♥♥♥ I like cats ♥♥♥
```

*PHP Info:*

PHP Version: 5.3.6-13 ubuntu 3.5

Regex Library: Bundled library enabled

Comment: http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/17340.aspx

Comment: Works as expected. There is something different with your input, or you are applying it wrong elsewise.

Comment: I added how I test it, and it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `#`

It should be this RegEx instead in your preg_replace call:

```
/&#[a-z\d]+;/i
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something like this. I also put a ? after # to match ones like &lt;

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [global modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (e)